# Issue with ressources files in CF

Tags: compact-framework, cab

I've done a compact framework app with sevral ressource files for globalization, and packagd everything into a CAB file.

My problem is that some of this ressources files seem to be unreadable (changing culture goes to default culture). All this ressource file are identical, excepte of course for translation. And when I copy files generated before packaging to the mobile device, everything works fine.

Any idea ?

Regards,

Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that CAB files don't support source files with the same name, so your resource.dll file is getting a bunch of copies of the first one.  You have to rename the *source* files, then use the CAB file to rename them back to the original on the destination.  It's a little convoluted, but there's no other way.

Ilya gives a decent description of it in the CF [newsgroup here](http://www.developmentnow.com/g/18_2006_3_0_0_711182/Resources-dll-do-not-update-cab-third-try-in-this-NG-MS-Bug-.htm).